# document.getElementsByClassName() not working like getElementById does?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can getElementsByClassName change style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/can-getelementsbyclassname-change-style)

I am trying to "fix" the "new" YouTube using Greasemonkey, I've been getting things to work as they should when it's with ID's, however I have been unable to modify anything with a class, it appears I am unable to select it or whatever anyways.

I have been trying to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("video-extras-sparkbar-likes").style.height='10px';
```

However it isn't working. :\

I'm not very familiar with Greasemonkey and what not, so would there be a reason why though my browser supports this, Greasemonkey may not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to loop through the results, like this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('video-extras-sparkbar-likes');
for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++) { 
  divs[i].style.height = '10px';
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that would work and all, however it doesn't seem to be working with Greasemonkey, or at least with this particular YouTube element.